# Animated object-scale with another object for growing leaves on a tree

Tags: animation

I like to animate a growing tree. I already done the tree trunk and branches via curves and a Taper Object (used Map Taper an Fill Caps). The leave growth I like to do via the object scale. Scale 0.01 to 1.

But the problem: The growth of the single leaves should only start when the branches reach the leaves. Is there a way using an object as a "activator" for the scale of the single leaves?

As an option I was thinking about using particles and Dynamic Paint. (Scale a Spehere as activator for the growing leaves).

But is there a way to do it without a Particle System too?

Some suggestion would be great! Thank you for any tips.

Comment: I would suggest looking at [animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) or [sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I already thought about using the Animation Nodes Addon, but it looks really hard for beginners. So maybe there is a solution with regular blender materials?

Comment: Look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmkiRjv7j5c) tutorial

Comment: @schustudrai Thanks for the link, it's a very interesting tut. But because I'm never have worked with the animation node addon, I decide to go with a particle system for the leaves and using dynamic paint. But I'm sure for an advanced user it would be no problem to solve it via animation nodes.